# how to use spring framework data access to get data to populate tableview in javafx

Tags: java, spring, javafx

The is the query i'm using to retrieve data from the data source

public List getRandomRecords()
  {
    String sql = "SELECT name,address,age,position,recordNo,location FROM records ORDER BY rand() ASC LIMIT 200";
    List records = new ArrayList();

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = this.jdbcSimple.queryForList(sql, new Object[0]);

for (Map row : rows) {
  Record record = new Record((String)row.get("name"), (String)row.get("insuranceId"), ((String)row.get("age")), (String)row.get("shalfNo"), (String)row.get("recordNo"), (String)row.get("location"));

  records.add(record);
}

return records;
```

}

**The following code is the initialize method for javafx to build the UX**

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
  Model dataResource = new Model();
  List records = dataResource.getRandomRecords();
  data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  data.setAll(records);

  ObservableList<Object> rows = FXCollections.observableList(data);

  //tableView and tableColumn configuration
  tblColName.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(0));
       }
}); 

  tblColInsurance.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(1));
       }
}); 

  tblColRecord.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(2));
       }
}); 

  tblColShalf.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(3));
       }
}); 

  tblColLocation.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(4));

       }
}); 

  tblColAge.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {         

       @Override
       public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) {

           return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(0));
       }
}); 

tblRecords.setItems(rows);

}
```

Can anybody read through the code and show me how to populate the tableview using the method i provided or make any suggest to this code.

***Note: the data access would be run under Thread. Thank you in advance.***

Comment: Try to describe what you are doing. Just posting code and "fix it" or "guess what" is not enough. Where is your Spring integration? How do you want to achieve it?

Comment: @zenbeni, thank you for quick responses, what i want to do is to pass the result return from spring data access which the signature of the method is  **List queryForList(String sql, Class elementType)** and i want to pass it result to a tableview.setItems() which accept observableList

Comment: You made a special bindable object "Record" with StringProperty fields?

Comment: yes, i'm able to solve the it by change @FMXL private TableView<?> to TableView<Record> that is the bindable Object i created. Thanks